# What's the practical difference between std::nth_element and std::sort?

Tags: c++

I've been looking at the std::nth_element algorithm which apparently:

> Rearranges the elements in the range [first,last), in such a way that
>   the element at the resulting nth position is the element that would be
>   in that position in a sorted sequence, with none of the elements
>   preceding it being greater and none of the elements following it
>   smaller than it. Neither the elements preceding it nor the elements
>   following it are guaranteed to be ordered.

However, with my compiler, running the following:

```
    vector<int> myvector;
    srand(GetTickCount());

    // set some values:
    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
        myvector.push_back(rand());

    // nth_element around the 4th element
    nth_element (myvector.begin(), myvector.begin()+4, myvector.end());

    // print results
    for (auto it=myvector.begin(); it!=myvector.end(); ++it)
        cout << " " << *it;

    cout << endl;
```

Always returns a completely sorted list of integers in exactly the same way as std::sort does.  Am I missing something?  What is this algorithm useful for?

**EDIT**: Ok the following example using a much larger set shows that there is quite a difference:

```
    vector<int> myvector;
    srand(GetTickCount());

    // set some values:
    for ( int i = 0; i < RAND_MAX; i++ )
        myvector.push_back(rand());

    // nth_element around the 4th element
    nth_element (myvector.begin(), myvector.begin()+rand(), myvector.end());

    vector<int> copy = myvector;
    std::sort(myvector.begin(), myvector.end());

    cout << (myvector == copy ? "true" : "false") << endl;
```

Comment: Just because your implementation seems to do it for some simple examples, does not mean that it always does it, nor that all other implementations do it.

Comment: What compiler, what library implementation? Try larger arrays in the order of 10000s.

Comment: Well using `sort` internally as an alias for `nth_element` fulfils the formal defition.

Comment: As you can see [here](http://ideone.com/xbOJV), that's not always the case.

Comment: @AndreasBrinck: But `sort` is O(n.log(n)), whereas `nth_element` is required to be O(n)...

Comment: @Oli Yes, you're right. My bad.

Comment: By the way, in your second example there should be a difference anyway, as you use two different ordering criteria (why the lambda, anyway?).

Comment: @ChristianRau Yes, my bad, in the case of the large set, it was so unsorted that I thought it was the other way around.  But quite logically they both default to operator<

Answer (score 54, accepted):

It's perfectly valid for [`std::nth_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) to sort the entire range for fulfilling the documented semantic - however, doing so will fail at meeting the required complexity (linear). The key point is that it *may* do so, but it doesn't *have to*.

This means that `std::nth_element` can bail out early - as soon as it can tell what the `n'th` element of your range is going to be, it can stop. For instance, for a range

```
[9,3,6,2,1,7,8,5,4,0]
```

asking it to give you the fourth element may yield something like

```
[2,0,1,3,8,5,6,9,7,4]
```

The list was partially sorted, just good enough to be able to tell that the fourth element in order will be `3`.

Hence, if you want to answer 'which number is the fourth-smallest' or 'which are the four smallest' numbers then `std::nth_element` is your friend.

If you want to get the four smallest numbers *in order* you may want to consider using [`std::partial_sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort).

Answer (score 10):

The implementation of std::nth_element looks as follows:

```
void _Nth_element(_RanIt _First, _RanIt _Nth, _RanIt _Last, _Pr _Pred)
{
    for (; _ISORT_MAX < _Last - _First; )
        {   // divide and conquer, ordering partition containing Nth
        pair<_RanIt, _RanIt> _Mid =
            _Unguarded_partition(_First, _Last, _Pred);

        if (_Mid.second <= _Nth)
            _First = _Mid.second;
        else if (_Mid.first <= _Nth)
            return; // Nth inside fat pivot, done
        else
            _Last = _Mid.first;
        }

    _Insertion_sort(_First, _Last, _Pred);  // sort any remainder
}
```

where ISORT_MAX defined as 32.

So if your sequence is shoter than 32 elements it just performs InsertionSort on it.
Therefore your short sequence is full sorted.

Comment: This code snippet explains why short sequences are fully sorted, making us wonder how this is possible with O(n) complexity. The implementation uses Selection algorithm until the remaining range is no more than ISORT_MAX and then sorts this range [_First, _Last] by Insertion sort.

Comment: It is O(n) on average. And sorting 32 elements array takes small amount of operations steps, we can count it as a constant asymptotically. @DavidKhosid

Comment: Which implementation? The Standard only defines what the library has to do; individual implementors decide how it's achieved, and you didn't cite  which implementor's stdlib this is from. A quick Google suggests to me that it's from STL or some derivative thereof, but I shouldn't have to search.

Answer (score 7):

`std::sort` sorts all the elements. `std::nth_elenemt` doesn't. It just puts the nth element in the nth positions, with smaller or equal elements on one side and larger or equal elements on the other. It is used if you want to find the nth element (obviously) or if you want the n smallest or largest elements. A full sort satisfies these requirements.

So why not just perform a full sort and get the nth element? Because `std::nth_element` has the requirement of having O(N) complexity, whereas `std::sort` is O(Nlog(N)). `std::sort` cannot satisfy the complexity requirement of `std::nth_element`.
If you do not need complete sorting of the range, it is advantageous to use it.

As for your example, when I run similar code on GCC 4.7, I get the expected results:

```
  for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    myvector.push_back(rand()%32); // make the numbers small

  cout << myvector << "\n";
// nth_element around the 4th element
  nth_element (myvector.begin(), myvector.begin()+4, myvector.end());
  cout << myvector << "\n";
  std::sort(myvector.begin(), myvector.end());
  cout << myvector << "\n";
```

produces

```
{ 7, 6, 9, 19, 17, 31, 10, 12, 9, 13 }
{ 9, 6, 9, 7, 10, 12, 13, 31, 17, 19 }
{ 6, 7, 9, 9, 10, 12, 13, 17, 19, 31 }
               ^
```

where I've used a custom made `ostream operator<<` to print out the results.

Answer (score 0):

I have compared execution times of std::sort vs. std::nth_element when running on a large vectors (512MB) of random unsigned long long's and taking middle element of it. Yes, I know it is O(N log(N)) vs O(N), anyway somehow I expected std::nth_element(mid) to be about twice as fast as std::sort, as it should be interested in "sorting" about half of elements. Results surprised me a bit, that's why I'm sharing them:

```
timeSort = 217407 (msec)
timeNthElement = 18218 (msec)
```

**std::sort was about 12 times slower**

Here is the piece of code I used (it is using windows.h) :

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    static const size_t NUMELEM = 512 * 1024 * 1024;
    static const size_t NUMITER = 3;
    std::vector<unsigned long long> vec1(NUMELEM);
    std::vector<unsigned long long> vec2(NUMELEM);
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 rand(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned long long> dist(0, NUMELEM * 2);

    unsigned long long timeNthElement = 0;
    unsigned long long timeSort = 0;

    for (size_t j = 0; j < NUMITER; ++j)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < NUMELEM; ++i)
        {
            unsigned long long val = dist(rand);
            vec1[i] = val;
            vec2[i] = val;
        }
        ULONGLONG t1 = GetTickCount64();
        std::sort(begin(vec1), end(vec1));
        ULONGLONG t2 = GetTickCount64();
        std::nth_element(begin(vec2), begin(vec2)+NUMELEM/2, end(vec2));
        ULONGLONG t3 = GetTickCount64();
        if (vec1[NUMELEM / 2] != vec2[NUMELEM / 2])
        {
            Sleep(0); // I put a breakpoint here but of course never caught it...
        }
        timeSort += t2 - t1;
        timeNthElement += t3 - t2;
    }

    std::cout << "timeSort = " << timeSort << std::endl;
    std::cout << "timeNthElement = " << timeNthElement << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```